# Python MultiProcessing make tkinter GUI appear again

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I am learning to create a gui to start multiprocessing printing.
When i click start button, it draw the gui again. is there anyway to limit it to run multiprocessing printing only?

Created the gui.py :

```
def stopstart():
    global instance

    if startbtn['text']=="start":
            # Multiprocessing start here
            RunMultiProcessor()
            # End of Multiprocessing
            startbtn.configure(text="END")
            startbtn.configure(bg="#ff8a65") 
        else:
            popuptimer()
    else:
        startbtn.configure(text="start")
        startbtn.configure(bg="#e2f1f8")

startbtn = Button(leftframe, text = "start",
            background = "#e2f1f8", fg = "#000000",bd=1,command = stopstart)
startbtn.pack(side = TOP,expand = FALSE,fill = X)
```

Created the multiprocessing.py :

```
def run():
    print("printing")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("print end")

def RunMultiProcessor():
    for _ in range(2):
           processes[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=run,))
                processes[i].start()
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#programming-guidelines), particularly the part about "Safe importing of main module".  New processes import your Python script again, so code that should only run once must be protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':`.  You haven't made a [mcve] but my guess is it isn't protected properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mark Tolonen for the answer. Below is the final code.

```
def stopstart():
    global instance

    if startbtn['text']=="start":
            # Multiprocessing start here
            RunMultiProcessor()
            # End of Multiprocessing
            startbtn.configure(text="END")
            startbtn.configure(bg="#ff8a65") 
        else:
            popuptimer()
    else:
        startbtn.configure(text="start")
        startbtn.configure(bg="#e2f1f8")

startbtn = Button(leftframe, text = "start",
            background = "#e2f1f8", fg = "#000000",bd=1,command = stopstart)
startbtn.pack(side = TOP,expand = FALSE,fill = X)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    top.mainloop()
```